# How to find tag with particular text with Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How to find `text I am looking for` in the following HTML (line breaks marked with `\n`)?

```html
...
<tr>
  <td class="pos">\n
      "Some text:"\n
      <br>\n
      <strong>some value</strong>\n
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="pos">\n
      "Fixed text:"\n
      <br>\n
      <strong>text I am looking for</strong>\n
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="pos">\n
      "Some other text:"\n
      <br>\n
      <strong>some other value</strong>\n
  </td>
</tr>
...
```

The code below returns first found value, so I need to filter by `"Fixed text:"` somehow.

```
result = soup.find('td', {'class' :'pos'}).find('strong').text
```

UPDATE: If I use the following code:

```
title = soup.find('td', text = re.compile(ur'Fixed text:(.*)', re.DOTALL), attrs = {'class': 'pos'})
self.response.out.write(str(title.string).decode('utf8'))
```

then it returns just `Fixed text:`, not the `<strong>`-highlighted text in that same element.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can pass a regular expression to the text parameter of `findAll`, like so:

```
import BeautifulSoup
import re

columns = soup.findAll('td', text = re.compile('your regex here'), attrs = {'class' : 'pos'})
```

Comment: Thanks, Peter. But it finds **Fixed text:** in result and not **text I am looking for**.

Comment: This is the marked answer, but doesn't solve the question. The answer is in the post though

Comment: @LA_ Is `soup.find(...)` starts with `body` tag or from the html root?

Answer (score 32):

This post got me to my answer even though the answer is missing from this post. I felt I should give back.

The challenge here is in the inconsistent behavior of `BeautifulSoup.find` when searching with and without text.

**Note:**
If you have BeautifulSoup, you can test this locally via:

```
curl https://gist.githubusercontent.com/RichardBronosky/4060082/raw/test.py | python
```

**Code:** https://gist.github.com/4060082

```
# Taken from https://gist.github.com/4060082
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen
from pprint import pprint
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/RichardBronosky/4060082/raw/test.html').read())
# I'm going to assume that Peter knew that re.compile is meant to cache a computation result for a performance benefit. However, I'm going to do that explicitly here to be very clear.
pattern = re.compile('Fixed text')

# Peter's suggestion here returns a list of what appear to be strings
columns = soup.findAll('td', text=pattern, attrs={'class' : 'pos'})
# ...but it is actually a BeautifulSoup.NavigableString
print type(columns[0])
#>> <class 'BeautifulSoup.NavigableString'>

# you can reach the tag using one of the convenience attributes seen here
pprint(columns[0].__dict__)
#>> {'next': <br />,
#>>  'nextSibling': <br />,
#>>  'parent': <td class="pos">\n
#>>       "Fixed text:"\n
#>>       <br />\n
#>>       <strong>text I am looking for</strong>\n
#>>   </td>,
#>>  'previous': <td class="pos">\n
#>>       "Fixed text:"\n
#>>       <br />\n
#>>       <strong>text I am looking for</strong>\n
#>>   </td>,
#>>  'previousSibling': None}

# I feel that 'parent' is safer to use than 'previous' based on http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names
# So, if you want to find the 'text' in the 'strong' element...
pprint([t.parent.find('strong').text for t in soup.findAll('td', text=pattern, attrs={'class' : 'pos'})])
#>> [u'text I am looking for']

# Here is what we have learned:
print soup.find('strong')
#>> <strong>some value</strong>
print soup.find('strong', text='some value')
#>> u'some value'
print soup.find('strong', text='some value').parent
#>> <strong>some value</strong>
print soup.find('strong', text='some value') == soup.find('strong')
#>> False
print soup.find('strong', text='some value') == soup.find('strong').text
#>> True
print soup.find('strong', text='some value').parent == soup.find('strong')
#>> True
```

Though it is most certainly too late to help the OP, I hope they will make this as the answer since it does satisfy all quandaries around finding by text.

Comment: @BrunoBronosky, It's been 5 years and you are still coming back to this documentation that you made. Thank you for taking the time to write this. You really appreciate yourself.

Comment: @BrunoBronosky, It's now been 10 years and the magic is still there. /me hums [Foreigner - Feels Like The First Time](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CK6jKL2qWxo) ☮️❤️

Answer (score 13):

With bs4 4.7.1+ you can use :contains pseudo class to specify the `td` containing your (filter) search string. You can then use a descendant child combinator, in this case, to move to the `strong` containing target text:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<tr>
  <td class="pos">\n
      "Some text:"\n
      <br>\n
      <strong>some value</strong>\n
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="pos">\n
      "Fixed text:"\n
      <br>\n
      <strong>text I am looking for</strong>\n
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="pos">\n
      "Some other text:"\n
      <br>\n
      <strong>some other value</strong>\n
  </td>
</tr>'''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('td:contains("Fixed text:") strong').text)
```

---

[soupsieve 2.1.0 onwards:](https://github.com/facelessuser/soupsieve/releases)

> NEW: In order to avoid conflicts with future CSS specification
> changes, non-standard pseudo classes will now start with the :-soup-
> prefix. As a consequence, :contains() will now be known as
> :-soup-contains(), though for a time the deprecated form of
> :contains() will still be allowed with a warning that users should
> migrate over to :-soup-contains().
>
> NEW: Added new non-standard pseudo class :-soup-contains-own() which
> operates similar to :-soup-contains() except that it only looks at
> text nodes directly associated with the currently scoped element and
> not its descendants.

Quote from @facelessuser github page.

Answer (score 6):

Since `Beautiful Soup 4.4.0.` a parameter called `string` does the work that `text` used to do in the previous versions.

`string` is for finding strings, you can combine it with arguments that find tags: Beautiful Soup will find all tags whose .string matches your value for the string. This code finds the  tags whose .string is “Elsie”:

```
soup.find_all("td", string="Elsie")
```

For more information about string have a look this section https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-string-argument

Comment: What if the tag changes, so you can't be explicit about the tag like in this case with `td`. What can I do in that case?

Answer (score 2):

A solution for finding a anchor tag if having a particular keyword would be the following:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen,Request
from urllib.parse import urljoin,urlparse

rawLinks=soup.findAll('a',href=True)
for link in rawLinks:
    innercontent=link.text
    if keyword.lower() in innercontent.lower():
        print(link)
```

Comment: this answer is for finding a anchor tag if having a particular keyword

Answer (score 1):

```py
result = soup.find('strong', text='text I am looking for').text
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Beautiful Soup's CSS selector method.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import Tag
from typing import List

# This will work as of BeautifulSoup 4.9.1.
result: List[Tag] = BeautifulSoup(html_string, 'lxml').select(
    'tr td strong:contains("text I am looking for")'
    )
print(result)
```

> [<strong>text I am looking for</strong>]

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this with some simple [gazpacho](https://github.com/maxhumber/gazpacho) parsing:

```
from gazpacho import Soup

soup = Soup(html)
tds = soup.find("td", {"class": "pos"})
tds[1].find("strong").text
```

Which will output:

> text I am looking for