# How to make regex with unicode symbols?

Tags: python, regex

I need to make regex which will capture the following:

```
Fixed unicode text:
<br>
<strong>
   text I am looking for
</strong>
```

I do something like

```
regex = re.compile(unicode('Fixed unicode text:.*','utf-8'))
```

How to modify that to capture remaining text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply prefix `u` (in Python 2.x, nothing in Python 3) to get a unicode string, and use parentheses to capture the remaining text, like this:

```
import re
haystack = u'Fixed unicode text:\n<br><strong>\ntext I\nam looking for</strong>'
match = re.search(ur'Fixed unicode text:(.*)', haystack, re.DOTALL)
print(match.group(1))
```

However, it looks like your input is HTML. If that's the case, you should [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) use a regular expression, but parse the HTML with [lxml](http://lxml.de/parsing.html#parsing-html), [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), or another HTML parser.

Comment: Thanks, phihag. I've tried to add line breaks support here (`re.M | re.S | re.U`), but it doesn't capture the whole text. What can be the reason? (see updated question) And, I use BeautifulSoup. I need this regex to be used with BeautifulSoup ;).

Comment: @LA_ Neither MULTILINE(M) nor UNICODE(U) have an effect for your regexp. Specifying `DOTALL`(S) is enough. I updated the answer to include that.

Comment: hmm, looks like there is some problem with BeautifulSoup - still it captures just one line. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9007653/how-to-find-tag-with-particular-text-with-beautiful-soup

Comment: Umm, if you're using an HTML parser, you use its traversal and selection methods, namely XPath, not regular expressions. In any case, can you post the code (including the input - use `\n` to encode newlines) that fails, and explain how it fails?

Comment: I've updated original question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9007653/how-to-find-tag-with-particular-text-with-beautiful-soup