# find a particular tag using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, tags, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the town and state for a given zip code using the following site:

```
http://www.zip-info.com/cgi-local/zipsrch.exe?zip=10023&Go=Go
```

Using the following code I get all the `tr` tags:

```
import sys
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get("http://www.zip-info.com/cgi-local/zipsrch.exe?zip=10023&Go=Go")
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
print soup.find_all('tr')
```

how do I find a particular `tr` tag?  in exmaples like this: [How to find tag with particular text with Beautiful Soup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9007653/how-to-find-tag-with-particular-text-with-beautiful-soup) you already know the text you are looking for.  what do I use if I don't know the text ahead of time?

**EDIT**

i've now added the following and get nowhere:

```
for tag in soup.find_all(re.compile("^td align=")):
    print (tag.name)
```

Comment: well, which `tr` tag do you want to find?

Comment: I don't see any names so I don't know now to identify a particular `tr` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I would navigate until that point in the `html` source with a mix of `find()` and `find_all()` calls, because I cannot diferenciate from other `<td>` elements based in poistion, attributes or something else:

```
import sys 
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

l = list()


r = requests.get("http://www.zip-info.com/cgi-local/zipsrch.exe?zip=10023&Go=Go")
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

for table in soup.find('table'):
    center = table.find_all('center')[3]
    for tr in center.find_all('tr')[-1]:
        l.append(tr.string)

print(l[0:-1])
```

Run it like:

```
python script.py
```

That yields:

```
[u'New York', u'NY']
```

Comment: Thanks!  But, I can't get that to work.  I'm trying to break your code out into snippets to figure it out.  What is `elem[1]`?

Comment: @dwstein: `enumerate()` returns a tuple, which first position is the index and second position is the value. I do this to avoid to print the third value of the table.

Comment: if there's any way you could break out that long line a little more, it would be very helpful. I don't understand what all the bracketed numbers are.

Comment: @dwstein: I've changed the approach to use different `for` loops and save all data in a list.

Answer (score 0):

After I took a look at the HTML code of the website you provided, I will say the best way to locate will be "text based location" instead of class, id based ..etc.

First you can easily identify the `header` row based on the text using the key word "Mail", and then you can easily get the row that contains the content you want.

Here is my code:

```
import urllib2, re, bs4
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.zip-info.com/cgi-local/zipsrch.exe?zip=10023&Go=Go"))
# find the header, then find the next tr, which contains your data
tr = soup.find(text=re.compile("Mailing")).find_next("tr")
name, code, zip = [ td.text.strip() for td in tr.find_all("td")]
print name
print code
print zip
```

After you print them out they look like this:

```
New York
NY
10023
```