# BeautifulSoup: How to get the nearest tag

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have an xml file with the following data

```
<year>2013</year>
<youSaveSpend>2500</youSaveSpend>
<yourMpgVehicle>
<avgMpg>32.261695541</avgMpg>
<cityPercent>43</cityPercent>
<highwayPercent>57</highwayPercent>
</yourMpgVehicle>

<year>2013</year>
<youSaveSpend>3000</youSaveSpend>
<yourMpgVehicle>
<avgMpg>33.383275416</avgMpg>
<cityPercent>49</cityPercent>
<highwayPercent>51</highwayPercent>
</yourMpgVehicle>

<year>2012</year>
<youSaveSpend>2500</youSaveSpend>
<yourMpgVehicle>
<avgMpg>36.210640188</avgMpg>
<cityPercent>32</cityPercent>
<highwayPercent>68</highwayPercent>
</yourMpgVehicle>
```

I want to use BeautifulSoup to return a list of avgMpg for only year 2013? How can I do that?

My current effort has been:

```
for item in soupedCarAvgMpgPage.findAll('year'):
    listOfYears.append(''.join(item.findAll(text=True)))

for item in soupedCarAvgMpgPage.findAll('avgmpg'):
    listOfAvgMpg.append(''.join(item.findAll(text=True)))

print listOfYears
print listOfAvgMpg;

dictionaryYearToAvgMpg = dict(zip(listOfYears, listOfAvgMpg));
```

but the dictionary does not accept duplicates :S

Comment: Please include your current efforts, we will help you fix it. But well, this ain't a code-writing service.

Comment: Where are you getting stuck?  Why are you not interested in using the native python library for [xml](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)

Comment: So why not [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9007653/how-to-find-tag-with-particular-text-with-beautiful-soup)

Comment: Firstly, this XML is not strictly well-formed if one is expected to match a tag with subsequent tags in order to get a relation between them. The elements are supposed to be inside another tag. Secondly, you can just not use `dict`, right? Just iterate over the values?

Comment: To extend over your almost-solution, you can actually do: `[avgMpg for year, avgMpg in zip(listOfYears, listOfAvgMpg) if year==2013]` to get what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we know the elements are going to be near each other, we can get there by searching through `next_siblings`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('mpg.xml') as f:
    contents=f.read()

mpgs = BeautifulSoup(contents)

def find_nearest_vehicle(elem):
    for sibling in elem.next_siblings:
        if sibling.name == 'yourmpgvehicle':
            return sibling

def find_avg_mpg(elem):
    for child in elem.children:
        if child.name == 'avgmpg':
            return child

year_2013 = [year for year in mpgs.find_all('year')
             if year.string == '2013']

avgmpg = [find_avg_mpg(find_nearest_vehicle(elem)).string
          for elem in year_2013]

print(avgmpg)
```

When I run this on your file, I get:

```
$ python3 mpg.py
['32.261695541', '33.383275416']
```

Comment: You're supposed to get `32.261` and `33.383`, right?

Comment: And to get the content, you can use `.string` instead of `next_element`

Comment: I think it's better to search for the tag named `avgMpg` in `.next_siblings` rather than hard-coding `over(elem, 4)`, since the whitespace might change.

Comment: Yeah, I just changed it to do the search, also. I will point out, as did you, that it's not really ideal to be parsing XML like this. You should have the elements grouped by whatever their grouping tag is, not physically near to one another like @user1607549 is doing.

Comment: Looks good. It's just that you don't really need to do search to find `avgmpg`, you can just do `find_nearest_vehicle(elem).avgmpg`.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, you can just change your final line into this:

```
result = [avgMpg for year, avgMpg in zip(listOfYears, listOfAvgMpg) if year=='2013']
```

Note that the `2013` is a string, not an integer.

Or, for shortened overall code (I converted the years into `int`s and `avgMpg`s into `float`s):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
soup = BS(string, 'lxml')
listOfYears = [int(el.string) for el in soup.find_all('year')]
listOfAvgMpg = [float(el.string) for el in soup.find_all('avgmpg')]
result = [avgMpg for year, avgMpg in zip(listOfYears, listOfAvgMpg) if year==2013]
print result
```

Result:

```
[32.261695541, 33.383275416]
```