# Find <td> tag value with specific text (Beautiful Soup)

Tags: html, regex, beautifulsoup

I need to extract data structured in a table from an HTML page. The data structure is all like this:

```
<td class="def">
            <div><b>First Name:</b></div>
        </td>
        <td class="def">Jhon
        </td>

<td class="def">
            <div><b>Last Name:</b></div>
        </td>
        <td class="def">Smith
        </td>
```

I need to extract data separately. For example

```
print first_name
>> Jhon
print last_name
>> Smith
```

A simple `soup.find('td', {'class':'def'})` won't work because it will match everything (First Name:, Jhon, Last Name:, Smith).

Any idea on how I can look for specific data? The same question was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9007653/how-to-find-tag-with-particular-text-with-beautiful-soup) but the solution given doesn't work at all...

Comment: see the second answer on that link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this way :

```
>>> tds = soup.find_all('td', {'class':'def'})
>>> [td.find_next_sibling('td', {'class':'def'}).text.strip() \
...     for td in tds if "First Name:" in s.text]
... 
[u'Jhon']
>>> [td.find_next_sibling('td', {'class':'def'}).text.strip() \
...     for td in tds if "Last Name:" in s.text]
... 
[u'Smith']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
First Name:.*?<td class="def">([^\n]+).*?Last Name:.*?<td class="def">([^\n]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lR9dR6/1)

**Explanation:**
`.`: Any character except line break [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wY6xS4/1)
`*`: Zero or more times [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wE3zV2/1)
`?`: Once or none [sample](https://regex101.com/r/qX9nZ9/1)
`( … )`: Capturing group [sample](https://regex101.com/r/qL1pP8/1)
`[^x]`: One character that is not x [sample](https://regex101.com/r/bB0vG6/1)
`\`: Escapes a special character [sample](https://regex101.com/r/aM5iM5/1)
`+`: One or more [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wV7cV2/1)