# BeautifulSoup.find_all(), can I select multiple tags and strings within those tags?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, findall

I am looking to scrape some data from a website. To preface, I am a novice. I am looking to specifically filter all the XML data returned based upon the Postal Code (postal code is under  `'item_teaser'`).

`<item lat="43.6437075296758" long="-80.083111524582" item_name="Acton Golf Club" item_url="http://www.ontariogolf.com/courses/acton/acton-gc/" item_teaser="4955 Dublin Line Acton, Ontario L7J 2M2"/>`

Above is an example of what I am trying to pull, but I want to filter everything through specific Postal Areas (the first 3 letters ex. L7J)

Can `find_all()` go through `item_teaser` find the associated strings such as "L7J, L2S, L2O, etc." and return those matching Postal Areas including the entire item?
The below code is wrong as I can't pull anything, but it's currently what I have.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.ontariogolf.com/app/map/cfeed.php?e=-63&w=-106&n=55&s=36"
xml = requests.get(url)
# I was just seeing if I could grab everything from the website which worked when I printed.
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml.content, 'lxml')
# I am trying to show all item teasers just to try it out, but I can't seem to figure it out
tag = soup.find_all(id="item_teaser")
print(tag)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if multiple strings [`matches list`] exist in another string [`attribute` with name = "`item_teaser`"]

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "http://www.ontariogolf.com/app/map/cfeed.php?e=-63&w=-106&n=55&s=36"
xml = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml.content, 'lxml')
input_tag = soup.find_all('item')

# put the list of associated strings here
matches = ["L7J", "L1S", "L2A"]

# print the result
for tag in input_tag:
    text= tag["item_teaser"]    
    if any(x in text for x in matches):
        print(text)
```

Comment: This is definitely more along the lines of what I am trying to do. in the "if any..." statement. Is "x" an arbitrary variable that is just trying to see what matches within text and matches? I am trying this code and it looks like what I want, but it's still returning the entire province, rather than the specific golf courses that match the 'matches' and 'text'.
If there isn't a postal code (such as L2S) in matches and in text, could that affect how the iteration works? Would Try Except work to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing:

```
tag = soup.find_all(id="item_teaser")
```

`BeautifulSoup` is looking for an HTML *ID* by the name of "item_teaser". However, "item_teaser" is not an *id*, it's an *attribute*.

To search for all `item-teaser`'s you can pass that tag as a *keyword argument* to `BeautifulSoup`:

```
for tag in soup.find_all(item_teaser=True):
    print(tag)
```

Additionarly, to access the `item-teaser`'s *attribute*, you can use tag`[<attribute>]`

```
for tag in soup.find_all(item_teaser=True):
    print(tag["item_teaser"])
```

Comment: Thank you!! That solved my issue for at least retrieving `item_teaser'!! Am I able to somehow use this to filter all items to only return items that have attributes in item_teaser match a specific string (such as the first 3 letters of a postal code)?

Comment: @SenadH To find tag by text consider looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9007653/how-to-find-tag-with-particular-text-with-beautiful-soup) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866000/using-beautifulsoup-to-find-a-html-tag-that-contains-certain-text)

Comment: That looks about what I am trying to do! I'll go look around and figure it out! I really appreciate the assistance.