# Is there a way to return one specific table from a webpage that has multiple tables in Python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm having trouble returning one particular table (the one titled 'BRN Substantial Shareholders') from this webpage - https://www.intelligentinvestor.com.au/shares/asx-brn/brainchip-holdings-ltd

I'm able to return all the tables using the below code.

```
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
all_tables = soup.find_all('table')
```

I've tried two different methods to try and scrape using bs but I can't seem to find a way - am I doing something wrong? Both of these output an empty list.

**Method 1**

```
# Scrape the substantial holder list
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

sub_headers = []
sub_holdings = []

for found_table in soup.find_all('table', class_=f'{ticker_code} + "Substantial Shareholders"'):
    sub_headers = found_table.find_all('th').append(sub_headers)
    sub_holdings = found_table.find_all('td').append(sub_holdings)

print(sub_headers)
print(sub_holdings)
```

**Method 2**

```
# Scrape the substantial holder list
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

all_headers = soup.find_all("th", class_=f"{ticker_code} Substantial Shareholders")
all_holdings = soup.find_all("tr", class_=f"{ticker_code} Substantial Shareholders")

sub_headers = []
sub_holdings = []

for header in all_headers:
    sub_headers.append(header.text)

for holding in all_holdings:
    holding.append(sub_holdings.text)

print(sub_headers)
print(sub_holdings)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To *only* scrape the table with the words *"BRN Substantial Shareholders"*, you can use a CSS selector to locate that table with:

```
table = soup.select_one("div:nth-of-type(11) table")
```

Comment: Oh thanks! Could you please help me understand what you are doing with "div:nth-of-type(11) table" section of the code? I've not seen this before.

Comment: @this selects the 11th `div` and then the `table` under that

Comment: Hmm ok - is there a more dynamic way to select it based on "Substantial Holding" text or something similar? The website divs change according to the company - I was just using this particular page as an example.  

An alternative I've tried is the below but because "Holding" is not unique, it returns more than one table.  

    `sub_table = pd.read_html(current_url, match='Holding')
    print(sub_table)`

Comment: @ivanchoz To find a tag by text see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9007653/how-to-find-tag-with-particular-text-with-beautiful-soup

Comment: Sorry you're going to have to explain in a bit more detail as I'm still learning - I've tried finding tags by text in the attempts I made in the OP?

Comment: @ivanchoz  To search a tag by text, try: `soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name == 'TAG-NAME' and "MY-TEXT" in tag.text)`

Comment: ok so I've managed to target the tag - how would I select the table inside that tag?
`sub_header = soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name == 'h3' and "Substantial Shareholders" in tag.text)
`
I've tried the below but returns an empty list? 
`sub_headers = []
sub_holding = []

for header in sub_headers:
    sub_tag.find_all("th").append(sub_headers)

for holding in sub_holding:
    sub_tag.find_all("td").append(sub_holding)

print(sub_headers)
print(sub_holding)
`

Comment: @ivanchoz please ask as a new question providing the correct HTML

Answer (score 0):

Found a much simpler method using below.
`sub_table = pd.read_html(current_url, match='Holding') print(sub_table)`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).